# How to use PCA for time-series predictions on highly correlated variables?

Tags: r, pca

say I have a dataset called Economic_Trends, and it contains 5 columns with 10 years of data. So for example,

```
Economic_Trend <- matrix(c(1:10, 2:11, rnorm(30)), byrow = FALSE, nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
```

Then this is the code that I run:

```
mu <- colMeans(Economic_Trend)

Econ_pca <- prcomp(Economic_Trend)

PCA1 <- Econ_pca$x[,1]
PCA2 <- Econ_pca$x[,2]


plot(Econ_pca$x[,1], Econ_pca$x[,2])
plot(lm(PCA1 ~ PCA2))
```

I see that I now have the two principal components, but I am not sure where to find the order because what if the years are messed up? I want to do prediction such that I can find the next 10 years, for example. How do I fit my PC's to a regression model, find the next steps in the time series, then reconstruct the original data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The big thing is to save your PCs as times series (ts) objects, to retain their order. Here's some code to help with that, and to plot the PCs:

```
require(xts)  ## Makes autoplot work
require(ggfortify)  ## Allows multiple PCs to be plotted in one graph
## Maybe some others

## Given code:
Economic_Trend <- matrix(c(1:10, 2:11, rnorm(30)), byrow = FALSE, nrow = 10, 
ncol = 5)
mu <- colMeans(Economic_Trend)

## Tweaked code: 
Econ_pca <- prcomp(Economic_Trend[,3:5]) ## First two columns are order 
## number
PCA1 <- ts(Econ_pca$x[,1])  ## Save first PC as a time series object
PCA2 <- ts(Econ_pca$x[,2])  ## Save second PC as a time series object
p <- autoplot(ts(cbind(PCA1,PCA2)), facets = FALSE) +  
     ## Create ggplot object plotting first 2 PCs
     ggtitle("First two PCs") + ylab("Econ ($?)") + ## Add plot and y-axis labels 
     theme_bw() +  ## Remove grayscale background grid
     theme(axis.text=element_text(size=rel(1)),legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
p  ## Display plot
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see your data. However, if there is 'trend' in names, then probably the series have trends and you want to forecast them.
It is better to apply a special version of PCA designed for time series. This is singular spectrum analysis (SSA).

```
library(Rssa)
library(lattice)
# Decompose 'EuStockMarkets' series with default parameters
ss <- ssa(EuStockMarkets, kind = "mssa")
rec <- reconstruct(ss, groups = list(Trend = 1:2))

foreca <- rforecast(ss, groups = list(Trend = 1:2), 
                    len = 200, only.new = TRUE)
data <- cbind(EuStockMarkets, rec$Trend, foreca)
xyplot(data, type = "l", superpose = TRUE,
       auto.key = list(columns = 3),
       col = c("blue", "darkgreen", "red", "violet"),
       lty = c(rep(2, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(3, 4)))
```

[image]